# Why Are Meta Stack Exchange Downvotes Mechanically Different?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, meta, privileges

I seem to have been ambushed by a subtle difference: elsewhere, Meta seemed to be about discussing solutions and expressing one's agreement or disagreement with them by upvotes or downvotes, with the latter being free (unlike on main sites). Yet at some point when I decided to voice my opinion on Meta Stack Exchange, it seems to have resulted in me losing the privilege by way of rep reduction, like on a main site. I didn't notice/realise what's going on until it became too late to undo.

Now, obviously I'm new to Meta.SE, and may not understand all the ways in which it is different from other metas, so I won't jump the gun and conclude that this is a bug. But trying to think of it as a feature, I can't figure out what purpose does it serve.

What makes it necessary to limit expression of disagreement with proposals or replies on Meta.SE in a way that isn't seen on other metas? Is this purpose currently relevant, or is it just a thing that remains from the time when the circumstances and necessities were different?

Comment: I don't think there is particular thought behind it, but for what it's worth, MSE counts as if it were a regular site, with all the trappings of one.